# Entity Framework : updating one-many relationships for an entity's child collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Consider an application dealing with houses and pictures. An entity named `House` has a **1:n** relationship to `HousePicture`.

The application allows the user to create and edit a `House`, and add/remove `HousePictures`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionMethod Edit(House h)
{
   //get an attached entity from the DB first.
   House original = db.Houses.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.ID==h.ID);

   UpdateModel(original);

   //collect all the uploaded pictures.
   original.HousePictures = GatherPicturesFromForm();


   db.SaveChanges();
   // the changes for the House are saved, 
   //but child collection Pictures are not.
}
```

How do you go about updating - adding new & deleting - the child collection when recreating the child collection from scratch?

- `Add()` or `Attach()` for each child in the collection?
- In what sequence do you need to Add or Attach the parent entity vs. the child collection?
- How to go about detecting the children to remove? Is this a feature of EF4 where deletes happen automatically by the framework, or does the developer need to write this logic?
- When adding more than one `HousePicture`, its ID == 0. The entity has the primary key in SQL Server has an auto-assigned PK of `int IDENTITY(1,1)`. This becomes a problem because EF4 thinks that 2+ child have the same ID.
- What are your recommendations on saving child collections using Entity Framework 4?
- Any other suggestions on making the persistence of 1:n collections easier when updating/adding/deleting?

Comment: How did you fix this problem? Saving EntityCollection back to db?

Answer (score 0):

In EF just add new objects to a collection and they'll automatically be persisted to the database with the correct foreign key values.

original.HousePictures.AddRange(GatherPicturesFromForm());

Comment: thanks... does this include deletes when child objects in the database don't exist in the 'new' set?

Comment: One would think it would especially if the OI foreign key requires that relationship on the child object.

Comment: unfortunately `EntityCollection<T>` doesn't have an `AddRange()`